# Generate random numbers from an exponential distribution

Tags: r, random

Using R, I want to generate 100 random numbers from an exponential distribution with a mean of 50. I want to store these numbers in a vector. I think I did it correctly, but I cannot find anything on the internet to verify my code. Here is my code:

```
vector <- rexp(100,50)
```

Comment: Well, `rexp` is using `rate` as second parameter,  and `mean=1/rate`, so `rexp(100, 1./50.0)` probably what you want. Did you try to bin and plot it?

Comment: Thank you for your response! I plotted a histogram with rexp(100, 50) and then I plotted a histogram with rexp(100, 1/50). I was reading in the help section of R and it does talk about the mean=1/rate. I am having a hard time understanding why mean=1/rate?

Comment: > I am having a hard time understanding why mean=1/rate?

Comment: `I am having a hard time understanding why mean=1/rate?`. Well, this is pretty standard definition. Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution. Here rate is equal to `\lambda` (table on the right), and mean is obviously inverse rate (or rate is inverse mean).

Comment: Let's put some analogy here. Suppose we have some events over time with exponential distribution (like, radioactive decay). Then under exponent you have multiplication of `lambda` and time, and it supposed to be dimensionless. Thus, if time is in seconds, then `lambda` is in inverse seconds and have meaning of decay RATE.

Comment: `I am having a hard time understanding why mean=1/rate?`  A concrete example:  If patients arrive to a hospital emergency room at a rate of 5 per hour, then the expected amount of time between two successive arrivals is 1/5 of an hour.  The mean time between occurrences is the inverse of the rate of the occurrences. If you think those arrivals are a Poisson process, then the inter-arrival time has an exponential distribution.  The exponential can be described in terms of either the rate or the mean, they're conceptually interchangeable, but you have to know which is being used.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I have a better understanding!

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

```
vector <- rexp(100, 1/50)
```

(answered in comments by @SeverinPappadeux )