# Basic insurance risk model - R

Tags: r, montecarlo, poisson

I'm currently working on an R code for a basic insurance risk process. 
it is part of an assignment, and I'm struggling with 3 things -

The question is in the image attached here. [Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W71Sk.png)

1) the time arrival is specified as a homogeneous Poisson process. I was wondering if the generation of E was right to address this.

2) I'm not sure how to include a summation in R

3) I'm also struggling with how to integrate the j effectively in the code? Am i using it the right way? I'm still new to R. my code seems wrong to me, i was just wondering if someone can point me in the right direction.

```
a = 10
n=100
t=0
l=10
for(t in 1:n){
  E <- rexp(n,l)
  if(t + E < t){ 
  t= t + E
  }else{
  if(t + E >=t){
    for(j in 1:t)
    R = a + 5*t - sum(X[j])
    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Does you code currently work? If not what are the errors? Do you have any sample inputs and outputs to help with debugging?

Comment: Check your `rexp` function call: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32338067/4468078

Comment: so currently the errors are -
Error in X : object 'X' not found

In addition: Warning messages:

1: In if (t + E < t) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (t + E >= t) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Along with X not being found - which i get why, but I'm not sure when X values should be introduced? Is it the beginning itself where X = 0?

I think my rexp function is working, but maybe I should be generating U? 
and using t =-1/lambda * ln(1-U)
(according to the comment above^^)

Comment: @nielson.96 Welcome at SO. I think your question is very interesting but possibly almost off-topic according to the SO guidelines (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and the community here is normally not willing to do your "homework". If you don't get good answers I suggest you post separate questions with one concrete problem per question incl. a minimal reproducible code example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). E. g. your question 1) looks like a statistical question but not an R question...

Comment: @RYoda Hello, thankyou for the warm welcome to SO. Ofcourse, I understand, this is not a place to ask the community to solve my "homework". As I said earlier, if someone can point me in the right direction (as you just did), little hints like that could actually help a person go a long way towards learning. And thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Can you please explain the variables (t [timestep in years?], n [number of trials] and l?). What is `X` (it is never set and causes an error). And as non-statistician I am wondering: Xi (single claim amount?) shall have a mean of 2, but you pass 10 instead of `1/2` (to derive the mean from the rate, see `?rexp`. And where is the independently calculated number of claims N(t))? The avg number of claim events per time step (lambda) is 10, so I guess you have to use `rpois(n,10)` somehow... Pls edit your question. PS: Use `ifelse` instead of `if` on vectorized (non-scalar) variables.